# find square in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In this image:

[image]

there are squares (3*3, 5*5 and 11*11)

How can I find small square (5*5)?

After applying a filter that only a small square remain in the image.

We can apply blur (size 5*5) filter on the image if square disappeared then we understand that square smaller of (5*5).

How can find square with matlab?

Comment: could you be more specific? Are you trying to find the coordinates of the small squares?

Comment: In that image your squares are different intensities, I assume you don't want to use thresholds to identify the right squares?

Comment: in resualt image i want keep only square with size (5*5) . no matter thresholds if you can use this.

Comment: Are you using the Matlab image processing toolbox ?

Comment: Is your image a JPEG, like in the question, or a matrix/bitmap that you *converted* to JPEG to post it here? I ask because compression artifacts created by converting to JPEG format can complicate certain image processing methods.

Comment: jpg or bmp no matter. how can use matlab  toolbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should convolve the image with the following kernel:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

If the white parts are 0 and the black parts are 1. if white is 1 and black is 0 switch +'s and -'s in the kernel.

You can use [conv2](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html). Check the link or wikipedia for more information about convolution. The full program is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

The result will be an image where all pixels are zero except the centers of the dark 5x5 squares.

Comment: i does not understand this.how can perform this with matlab.this mean that create a mtrix 5*5 and convert 0 to 1 and reverse

Comment: please more description about this.how can do this with matlab

Comment: @StackOverflow See the edit. I think that there are enough details now. If you don't understand something please be specific with your problem.

Comment: @Simon: How is this not finding the 11*11 square?

Comment: @Jonas You are right the solution was incorrect. I improved it a bit. Still it is not perfect. Maybe I will come up with something more robust later.